How to add a Gnome Calendar reminder in 24.04?
Just what the title says. When I edit a (non-all day) calendar event to add a reminder (e.g., 5 minutes before event), or even more than one reminder (e.g., 5 minutes, and 1 hour before event), it seemingly does so, but when I click "Save" (1) no alarm notifications occur, and (2) if I edit such events I find that no reminders have been set/saved.
How to add and actually save and respect a reminder in Gnome Calendar events in 24.04?

Not saving reminders is apparently a bug in 24.04.1 and Gnome Desktop 46. The bug is confirmed and queued for fixing.
A fix to gnome-calendar has been committed as version 46.1-0ubuntu2. You can currently install and test or use it in three steps by:
1. Editing (and possibly creating) /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources to add  noble-proposed to the end of the line beginning with Suites:.
2. Editing (possibly creating first) /etc/apt/preferences.d/proposed-updates to add:
# Configure apt to not automatically install proposed noble packages
Package: *
Pin: release a=noble-proposed
Pin-Priority: 400

3. Then apt install gnome-calendar/noble-proposed.
You will need to log out and back in for the changes to take effect.
